# How can use .map function instead of innerHTML() in react?

Tags: reactjs

In this scenario I have created a Dynamic table in reactJS, I am using `constructor`, `states` or `objects` or written a code for printing row and column table using `innerHTMl`, but I want to use `.map` function to create a table instead of `innerHTML`. So, in the `html` part how can I use `.map` function?

How can I use `.map` function for create row or column?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/JSXTransformer.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.29/browser.js"></script>
    <title>My First React File</title>
    <style>
        .level1 td,  .label1 tr {
          border: 1px solid black;
        }
        .level2 td, .label2 tr {
            border: 2px solid black;
        }
        .level3 td , .label3 tr {
            border: 3px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>    
    <script type="text/jsx">      
      class DynamicTable extends React.Component { 
          constructor(props) {
              super(props);            
              this.state = {
                  data: 'Dynamic Table', 
                  tblborder :'level1'
              }
              this.tableHead = this.tableHead.bind(this);
              this.all_row = 1;
              this.all_col = 1;
              this.dTable = "";
              this.index_count = 0;
              this.table_value = 1;    
              self = this;             
          };    
         tableHead(top_event) {
            this.setState({data: top_event.target.value});
          }
          tableRows(rows_event) {
              let text = "";
              let create_rows = 0;
              var id = rows_event.target.id;
              if (id == "all_row_range") {
                self.all_row = rows_event.target.value;
              } else {
                self.all_col = rows_event.target.value;
              }
              let dTable= document.getElementById('dynamic_tbody');
              while(create_rows < self.all_row) {
                  text += '<tr>';
                  for(let i = 0; i < self.all_col; i++){
                      text += '<td>Editable cells</td>';
                  }
                  text += '</tr>';
                  create_rows = create_rows + 1;
              }
              ReactDOM.findDOMNode(dTable).innerHTML = text;
              document.getElementById('dynamic_style_table').style.borderWidth = self.table_value;
              self.index_count = 0;
          } 
          tableBold(bold_value) {
            let v = bold_value.target.value;
            v = "level" + v;
            self.setState({tblborder : v})
          } 
          tableColumnEdit(edit_event) {
              let edit_value = document.getElementById("edit_cell_checkbox").checked;
              let tbody = document.getElementById("dynamic_tbody");
              let tr_tag = tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr");
              if(edit_value == true) {
                  for(let td_index = 0; td_index < tr_tag.length; td_index++) {
                     tr_tag[td_index].contentEditable = "true";
                  }
              } else {
                  for(let td_index = 0; td_index < tr_tag.length; td_index++) {
                     tr_tag[td_index].contentEditable = "false";
                  }
              }
          }
          render() {  
                const style = {
                  area_Left: {
                      float: 'left',
                      height: '397px',
                      width: '45%',
                      padding: '20px 20px',
                      lineHeight: '4',
                      background: '#21618C',
                      margin: '15px'
                  },
                  area_Right: {
                      float: 'right',
                      background: '#F5B7B1',
                      color: '#333',
                      height: '398px',
                      width: '45%',
                      padding: '20px 20px',
                      margin: '15px'
                  },
                  font_Size: {
                      font_Size: '13',
                      font: 'cursive',
                      fontWeight: 'bold',
                      color: '#333'
                  },
                  first_input: {
                      width: '162px',
                      height: '25px',
                      position: 'relative',
                      left: '49%'
                  },
                  rows_Border: {
                      border: "1px solid #333",
                      margin: '2px 0 0 2px',
                      width: '450px',
                      height: '70px'
                  },
                  text_Box: {
                      margin: '2px 0 0 0'
                  },
                  select_box: {
                      position: 'relative',
                      left: '34%',
                      width: '162px',
                      height: '25px'
                  },
                  position: {
                      position: 'relative',
                      left: '28%',
                      width: '89px',
                      height: '22px'
                  },
                  meter_first: {
                      position: 'relative',
                      left: '16%',
                      background: 'red'
                  },
                  meter_second: {
                      position: 'relative',
                      left: '11%'
                  }
              }
              return (
                  <div>
                      <form action="#" method="post">
                          <div class="container">
                            <div style={style.area_Left}>
                                <div class="form-group" style={style.text_Box}>
                                    <label htmlFor="first_text" style={style.font_Size}>Table name</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" style={style.first_input } type="text" name="first_text" id="first_text" value = {this.state.data} onChange = {this.tableHead}/>                  
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label htmlFor="all_row_range" style={style.font_Size}>Range for row increment/decrement </label>
                                    <input class="form-control" style={style.meter_first} type="range" name="all_row_range" id="all_row_range" min="1" max="5" onChange = {this.tableRows} defaultValue="0"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label htmlFor="all_col_range" style={style.font_Size}>Range for column increment/decrement </label>
                                    <input class="form-control" style={style.meter_second} type="range" name="all_col_range"  id="all_col_range" defaultValue="0" min="1" max="5" onChange = {this.tableRows}/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label htmlFor="bold_select_box" style={style.font_Size}>Boldness of border cell</label>
                                    <select class="form-control" style={style.select_box} name="bold_select_box" id="bold_select_box" onChange = {this.tableBold}>
                                        <option value="1">Level-1</option>
                                        <option value="2">Level-2</option>
                                        <option value="3">Level-3</option>

                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <label htmlFor="edit_cell_checkbox" style={style.font_Size}>Edit on cell of the table</label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" style={style.position} name="edit_cell_checkbox" id="edit_cell_checkbox" value="editing" onClick = {this.tableColumnEdit}/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div style={style.area_Right}>
                                <table style={style.rows_Border} id="dynamic_style_table" className={this.state.tblborder}>
                                        <caption><h3>{this.state.data}</h3></caption> 
                                    <tbody id="dynamic_tbody">

                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
              );
        }
      }
      React.render(<DynamicTable />,document.getElementById('app'));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your text to array in state like this

```
this.state.texts = []
```

Your `onChange` in `input` can be

```
(value) => this.setState({...state, texts: [...texts, value]})
```

And finally, you update your render function with this:

```
{
  texts.map(text => (<tr>....Your code....<tr>))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash to loop through range of numbers as below

Add lodash js in header

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Set initial state in constructor for create rows and columns. Then your function to create rows and columns will be as below

```
tableRows(rows_event) {
    var id = rows_event.target.id;
    if (id == "all_row_range") {
      self.setState({
          all_row: rows_event.target.value
      })
    } else {
      self.setState({
        all_col: rows_event.target.value
      })
    }

    document.getElementById('dynamic_style_table').style.borderWidth = self.table_value;
}
```

In render you will have

```
{_.range(0, this.state.all_row).map(row => {
return (
  <tr key={row}>
    {_.range(0, this.state.all_col).map(col => {
      return(
        <td key={col}>Editable cells</td>
      )
    })}
  </tr>
)})}
```

Your full working code here below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.29/browser.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
    <title>My First React File</title>
    <style>
        .level1 td,  .label1 tr {
          border: 1px solid black;
        }
        .level2 td, .label2 tr {
            border: 2px solid black;
        }
        .level3 td , .label3 tr {
            border: 3px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>    
    <script type="text/jsx">      
      class DynamicTable extends React.Component { 
          constructor(props) {
              super(props);            
              this.state = {
                  data: 'Dynamic Table', 
                  tblborder :'level1',
                  all_row: 1,
                  all_col: 1
              }
              this.tableHead = this.tableHead.bind(this);
              this.table_value = 1;    
              self = this;             
          };    

          tableHead(top_event) {
            this.setState({data: top_event.target.value});
          }

          tableRows(rows_event) {
              var id = rows_event.target.id;
              if (id == "all_row_range") {
                self.setState({
                  all_row: rows_event.target.value
                })
              } else {
                self.setState({
                  all_col: rows_event.target.value
                })
              }

              document.getElementById('dynamic_style_table').style.borderWidth = self.table_value;
          }

          tableBold(bold_value) {
            let v = bold_value.target.value;
            v = "level" + v;
            self.setState({tblborder : v})
          } 

          tableColumnEdit(edit_event) {
              let edit_value = document.getElementById("edit_cell_checkbox").checked;
              let tbody = document.getElementById("dynamic_tbody");
              let tr_tag = tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr");
              if(edit_value == true) {
                  for(let td_index = 0; td_index < tr_tag.length; td_index++) {
                     tr_tag[td_index].contentEditable = "true";
                  }
              } else {
                  for(let td_index = 0; td_index < tr_tag.length; td_index++) {
                     tr_tag[td_index].contentEditable = "false";
                  }
              }
          }

          render() {  
                const style = {
                  area_Left: {
                      float: 'left',
                      height: '397px',
                      width: '45%',
                      padding: '20px 20px',
                      lineHeight: '4',
                      background: '#21618C',
                      margin: '15px'
                  },
                  area_Right: {
                      float: 'right',
                      background: '#F5B7B1',
                      color: '#333',
                      height: '398px',
                      width: '45%',
                      padding: '20px 20px',
                      margin: '15px'
                  },
                  font_Size: {
                      font_Size: '13',
                      font: 'cursive',
                      fontWeight: 'bold',
                      color: '#333'
                  },
                  first_input: {
                      width: '162px',
                      height: '25px',
                      position: 'relative',
                      left: '49%'
                  },
                  rows_Border: {
                      border: "1px solid #333",
                      margin: '2px 0 0 2px',
                      width: '450px',
                      height: '70px'
                  },
                  text_Box: {
                      margin: '2px 0 0 0'
                  },
                  select_box: {
                      position: 'relative',
                      left: '34%',
                      width: '162px',
                      height: '25px'
                  },
                  position: {
                      position: 'relative',
                      left: '28%',
                      width: '89px',
                      height: '22px'
                  },
                  meter_first: {
                      position: 'relative',
                      left: '16%',
                      background: 'red'
                  },
                  meter_second: {
                      position: 'relative',
                      left: '11%'
                  }
              }

              return (
                  <div>
                      <form action="#" method="post">
                          <div class="container">
                            <div style={style.area_Left}>
                                <div class="form-group" style={style.text_Box}>
                                    <label htmlFor="first_text" style={style.font_Size}>Table name</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" style={style.first_input } type="text" name="first_text" id="first_text" value = {this.state.data} onChange = {this.tableHead}/>                  
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label htmlFor="all_row_range" style={style.font_Size}>Range for row increment/decrement </label>
                                    <input class="form-control" style={style.meter_first} type="range" name="all_row_range" id="all_row_range" min="1" max="5" onChange = {this.tableRows} defaultValue="0"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label htmlFor="all_col_range" style={style.font_Size}>Range for column increment/decrement </label>
                                    <input class="form-control" style={style.meter_second} type="range" name="all_col_range"  id="all_col_range" defaultValue="0" min="1" max="5" onChange = {this.tableRows}/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label htmlFor="bold_select_box" style={style.font_Size}>Boldness of border cell</label>
                                    <select class="form-control" style={style.select_box} name="bold_select_box" id="bold_select_box" onChange = {this.tableBold}>
                                        <option value="1">Level-1</option>
                                        <option value="2">Level-2</option>
                                        <option value="3">Level-3</option>

                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <label htmlFor="edit_cell_checkbox" style={style.font_Size}>Edit on cell of the table</label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" style={style.position} name="edit_cell_checkbox" id="edit_cell_checkbox" value="editing" onClick = {this.tableColumnEdit}/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div style={style.area_Right}>
                                <table style={style.rows_Border} id="dynamic_style_table" className={this.state.tblborder}>
                                        <caption><h3>{this.state.data}</h3></caption> 
                                    <tbody id="dynamic_tbody">
                                    {_.range(0, this.state.all_row).map(row => {
                                      return (
                                        <tr key={row}>
                                          {_.range(0, this.state.all_col).map(col => {
                                            return(
                                              <td key={col}>Editable cells</td>
                                            )
                                          })}
                                        </tr>
                                      )
                                    })}
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
              );
        }
      }
      ReactDOM.render(<DynamicTable />,document.getElementById('app'));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```